# NodeHandle class working

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorials, I read that creating an object of NodeHandle registers my program as a node with ROS master.

Where I find the code that helps me understand this in depth?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286181/nodehandle-class-working/) by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sources for `roscpp` can be found in `ros/ros_comm`. `NodeHandle` itself: [ros/ros_comm/clients/roscpp/src/libros/node_handle.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/src/libros/node_handle.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1